# CodeIgniter - Enter data into textbox and check for matching record from database on submit

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter application where I need to add some information in a form in my view page named `meal_add.php`. Here is the form:

```
 <div id="content" class="box">
                <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/meal2" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend id="add_employee_legend">
                            Add Meal Information
                        </legend>
                        <div>
                            <label id= "emp_id_add_label">Employee ID:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="emp_id" id = "employee_id_add" placeholder="Employee ID" required="1"/>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div>
                            <label id= "is_guest_add_label">Guests?</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name ="is_guest_checkbox" class ="guestcheck" value="1" onchange="valueChanged()"/>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div id = "guestnum" hidden = "true">
                            <label id= "num_of_guest_add_label">No. of Guests:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="num_of_guest" id = "num_of_guest_add" placeholder='0'/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label id= "remarks_add_label">Remarks:</label>
                            <textarea rows="1" cols="20" style="margin-left: 35px"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id = "meal_info_submit" value="Save Meal Information"/>
                        <button id = "cancel_button" onclick="location.href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/meal'">
                            Cancel
                        </button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

My controller method for add -

```
function meal2()
{
    if($_POST)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dacca');
        $mdata['emp_id'] = $this->input->post('emp_id');
        $mdata['entry_date'] = date('Y-m-d');
        $mdata['is_guest'] = $this->input->post('is_guest_checkbox');
        $mdata['num_of_guest'] = $this->input->post('num_of_guest');

        $mdata['remarks'] = $this->input->post('remarks');
        $res = $this->meal_model->insert_meal($mdata);
        if($res)
        {   
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Meal information added successfully');
            redirect("admin_logins/meal");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('admin_logins/meal_add');
    }

}
```

And my model method -

```
public function insert_meal($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('meal', $data);    
}
```

I have a table named `employee`, the structure is as follows:

```
    column              data type
      id                 int PK
    emp_id             varchar(15)
   emp_name            varchar(50)
 emp_mobile_no         varchar(15)
```

I have another table named `meal`, structure is as follows:

```
    column              data type
      id                 int PK
    emp_id             varchar(15)
   entry_date             date
   is_guest               int
 num_of_guest             int
   remarks                text
```

What I need to do is: whenever I'll enter an ID in Employee ID textbox in my form `meal_add.php` page, system will determine whether my entered id text matches with value of `employee.emp_id`. If a match is found, then data will be successfully saved in the `meal` table as `meal.emp_id`, and the value that will be saved is the corresponding `employee.id`(the value in the primary key column of `employee` table). If no match is found, a php flash message will be displayed that says ID doesn't exist on top of my `meal_add.php` view page. I know that a JOIN query is needed, but the text matching part seems very difficult to me and I can't figure out how to organize my code and where to put them. Please help me out.

My Database is MySQL.

**EDIT - 1:**

I've done this in my controller method -

```
    $temp = $this->input->post('emp_id');
    $sql = "SELECT e.id FROM employee AS e WHERE e.emp_id = ?";
    $mdata['emp_id'] = $this->db->query($sql, $temp)->emp_id;


    if($mdata['emp_id'] == '')
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Employee ID does\'nt exist');
        redirect("admin_logins/meal");
    }
```

No matter what value I'm providing in `$temp`, I always get the flash message and get redirected.

I've done this as well-

```
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($mdata);
    die();
```

And after doing `echo` and `print_r()`, I got this -

```
  A PHP Error was encountered

  Severity: Notice

  Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$emp_id

  Filename: controllers/admin_logins.php

  Line Number: 150

  Array
  (
      [emp_id] => 
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some massive changes:

Controller -

```
function meal2()
{
    if($_POST)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dacca');
        $temp = $this->input->post('emp_id');

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM employee WHERE emp_id = '$temp' ")->result_array();

        $mdata['emp_id'] = $query[0]['id'];

        if($mdata['emp_id'] == '')
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Employee ID doesn\'t exist');
            redirect("admin_logins/meal");
        }


        $mdata['entry_date'] = date('Y-m-d');
        $mdata['is_guest'] = $this->input->post('is_guest_checkbox');
        $mdata['num_of_guest'] = $this->input->post('num_of_guest');

        $mdata['remarks'] = $this->input->post('remarks');

        $res = $this->meal_model->insert_meal($mdata);
        if($res)
        {   
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Meal information added successfully');
            redirect("admin_logins/meal");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('admin_logins/meal_add');
    }

}
```

Also in another method named meal() in controller -

```
    $data['myQuery'] = $special_query = $this->db->query("SELECT m.id, e.emp_id, m.entry_Date, m.is_guest, m.num_of_guest, m.remarks FROM meal m LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.id = m.emp_id")->result_array();
```

Had to use a **LEFT JOIN** (my favorite) to retrieve the related information.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think what you are after is `$this->db->insert_id()`</strike>

Docs here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html

Also look at proper [form validation for codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html).

**UPDATE**

Sorry I misread when glancing at the question. Please look at [generating query results](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

```
$q = $this->db->query($sql, $temp);
if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
    // having a match means the emp_id is valid
    $row = $q->row();

    // you can now use $row->emp_id to insert to other table
    $ID = $row->emp_id;
} else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Employee ID does\'nt exist');
    redirect("admin_logins/meal");
}
```

Why is `emp_id` a varchar on the meal table? If it is foreign key, it would help if the types match and `int` is a lot faster when matching (joining tables).

Comment: `$this->db->insert_id()` in my controller? Wait a minute, I'm not just inserting any id, I want to insert id FROM ANOTHER TABLE WHERE ANOTHER TABLE.emp_id = $this->input->post('emp_id'). `id` is a primary key, int column, while `emp_id` is a non-primary key varchar column. Please look at the two table structures I've posted in my question. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Just saw your answer. It seems ok, although I haven't checked it yet, but I'll tomorrow morning. And you're right, `employee.emp_id` is varchar, but `meal.emp_id` shouldn't be, since it's a foreign key in `meal`, and primary key in `employee`, so it definitely should be int. I've already fixed that in my database, I just forgot to update my post acccrodingly.

Comment: Ok. I'm getting the right data while I tried your answer. But still there is a problem. When I'm doing this - `$mdata['emp_id'] = $row->emp_id`, and then `echo "<pre>"` and `print_r($madata)`, I get the following error - `A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$emp_id`